# how to shift items up and down in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote code.
when you click on the button function is called up, which will raise the div up one position over another div, and the same with the Down just down
Do you know how to do it ?
  http://jsfiddle.net/WmbmF/15/

```
<button type="submit" class="button" id="addk">Add div</button>
 <div class="body" style="float: left;">
```

and

```
var RL;
RL = 0;
$("#addk").click(function () {
       RL = RL + 1;
        RN = "Tekst" + RL;
         $("<div id='" + RN + "' class='we' > " +
          "<B>Kon" + RL +"</B>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button'  onclick='Add(" + RN + ");' >AddNext</button>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button'  onclick='Close(" + RN + ");' >Close</button>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button' onclick='Up(" + RN + ");' >Up</button>" +
           "<button type='submit' class='button' onclick='Down(" + RN + ");' >Down</button><br />" +
           "<br />"  + "<input type='text'>" + "<br /><br />" + '</div>').

         appendTo(".body");
    });
function Close (){
 $("#" + body.id + "").hide();
}
function Up (we){
//??
}
function Up (we){
//?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing Up() and Down()?  Give it a try and post that, you'll get lots more help.

Comment: Trying to do as in the example here but does not work http://jsfiddle.net/WmbmF/17/

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is what you want exactly but you could try this:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('up')) {
        $(this).closest('div').insertBefore($(this).closest('div').prev());
    } else {
        $(this).closest('div').insertAfter($(this).closest('div').next());
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8D7d/

Answer (score 0):

This way doesn't seem very user friendly, what happens if there are 100 items to move up and down?  I think a better way to achieve this would be to have a sortable list instead:

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default